# How to pass an argument containing double quote to a shell script function?

Tags: mysql, arguments, bash-functions

I have in pull_news.sh (variable declarations omitted):

```
dump_table () {
   mysqldump --user=${REMOTE_USERNAME} --password=${REMOTE_PASSWORDS} --host=${REMOTE_HOST} --port=${REMOTE_PORT} --single-transaction --lock-tables=false $@
}

pull_news(){
    dump_table --set-gtid-purged=OFF --where="INFOCODE IN (SELECT INFOCODE FROM info_an_newsrelation WHERE MKTPOSTFIX = '.OC')" ${REMOTE_DBNAME} info_an_newscontent > ${DUMPFILE}
}

pull_news
```

After

```
$ ./pull_news.sh
```

I got

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1044: Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'in' when selecting the database
```

The problem vanished if I remove the where-clause, so it seems to me that for some unknown reason shell only took the first word of my where-clause, and parsed the seconde word(the `IN`) as a database name.

Then I replaced it with

```
--where="\"INFOCODE IN (SELECT INFOCODE FROM info_an_newsrelation WHERE MKTPOSTFIX = '.OC')\""
```

but it didn't work. I don't know what to do now, any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unquoted `$@` is the issue. It expands to all the arguments of the function, and after that, makes them subject to [wordsplitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) (and globbing). Put it in quotes:

```
dump_table () {
   mysqldump --user=... --lock-tables=false "$@"
}
```

The other variables should be quoted too (`"${REMOTE_USERNAME}"`) just as a matter of principle, though usernames and database names aren't likely to contain whitespace (or glob characters)

The string you're actually passing as an argument there doesn't contain any double quotes. After the quote processing (removal) by the shell, it's just the string `--where=INFOCODE IN (SELECT ... = '.OC')` and that's the way `mysqldump` would see it, if you started it directly instead of through the other function. Putting the quotes in `"$@"` keeps it that way.

Of course the answer to the question in the title, you can pass literal double-quotes by backslash-escaping them or putting them in single quotes, as with any other command:

```
somefunc "their name was \"$name\"" 
somefunc 'their name was "John"'
```